# Vectorize repetitive math function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, mathematical-expressions

I have a mathematical function of this form `$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^N x^j * \sin(j*x)$` that I would like to compute efficiently in `Python`. N is of order ~100. This function f is evaluated thousands of times for all entries x of a huge matrix, and therefore I would like to improve the performance (profiler indicates that calculation of f takes up most of the time). In order to avoid the loop in the definition of the function f I wrote:

```
def f(x)
    J=np.arange(0,N+1)
    return sum(x**J*np.sin(j*x))
```

The issue is that if I want to evaluate this function for all entries of a matrix, I would need to use `numpy.vectorize` first, but as far as I know this not necessarily faster than a for loop.

Is there an efficient way to perform a calculation of this type?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Sack Overflow! ^^

Well, calculating `something ** 100` is some serious thing. But notice how, when you declare your array `J`, you are forcing your function to calculate `x, x^2, x^3, x^4, ...` (and so on) independently.

Let us take for example this function (which is what you are using):

```
def powervector(x, n):
    return x ** np.arange(0, n)
```

And now this other function, which does not even use NumPy:

```
def power(x, n):
    result = [1., x]
    aux = x
    for i in range(2, n):
        aux *= x               
        result.append(aux)
    return result
```

Now, let us verify that they both calculate the same thing:

```
In []: sum(powervector(1.1, 10))
Out[]: 15.937424601000005

In []: sum(power(1.1, 10))
Out[]: 15.937424601000009
```

Cool, now let us compare the performance of both (in iPython):

```
In [36]: %timeit sum(powervector(1.1, 10))
The slowest run took 20.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.52 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit sum(power(1.1, 10))
The slowest run took 5.28 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 µs per loop
```

It is faster, as you are not calculating all the powers of `x`, because you know that `x ^ N == (x ^ N - 1) * x` and you take advantage of it.

You could use this to see if your performance improves. Of course you can change `power()` to use NumPy vectors as output. You can also have a look at [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), which is easy to try and may improve performance a bit as well.

As you see, this is only a hint on how to improve some part of your problem. I bet there are a couple of other ways to further improve your code! :-)

### Edit

It seems that Numba might not be a bad idea... Simply adding `@numba.jit` decorator:

```
@numba.jit
def powernumba(x, n):
    result = [1., x]
    aux = x
    for i in range(2, n):
        aux *= x               
        result.append(aux)
    return result
```

Then:

```
In [52]: %timeit sum(power(1.1, 100))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.67 µs per loop

In [51]: %timeit sum(powernumba(1.1, 100))
The slowest run took 5.64 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.64 µs per loop
```

It seems Numba can do some magic there. ;-)

Comment: This is a great idea, and I will certainly implement something along these lines. However, in the future I'm expecting to replace the expression with something like sum_{j=0}^N g(x,C), for some function g, and therefore I'm trying to look for a more generic way to improve the code regardless of the function g.

Comment: @PythonBeginner: Numba will still apply in that case. Have a look at that project, you will not regret it! ;-)

Comment: First time I hear about Numba, I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

For a scalar `x`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = 0.5
>>> jj = np.arange(10)
>>> x**jj
array([ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.25      ,  0.125     ,  0.0625    ,
        0.03125   ,  0.015625  ,  0.0078125 ,  0.00390625,  0.00195312])
>>> np.sin(jj*x)
array([ 0.        ,  0.47942554,  0.84147098,  0.99749499,  0.90929743,
        0.59847214,  0.14112001, -0.35078323, -0.7568025 , -0.97753012])
>>> (x**jj * np.sin(jj*x)).sum()
0.64489974041068521
```

Notice the use of the `sum` method of numpy arrays (equivalently, use `np.sum` not built-in `sum`).

If your `x` is itself an array, use broadcasting:

```
>>> a = x[:, None]**jj
>>> a.shape
(3, 10)
>>> x[0]**jj == a[0]
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then sum over a second axis:

```
>>> res = a * np.sin(jj * x[:, None])
>>> res.shape
(3, 10)
>>> res.sum(axis=1)
array([ 0.01230993,  0.0613201 ,  0.17154859])
```